# Trying to get numeric values from a file to total them

Tags: input, output

I'm having issues with Python getting values from a text file. Which contains numbers so I can total them

but when I run the program it says the total number of families is 31 (which is correct)
but the total number of kids only say 2 (it should say 66)

here is my code. Any help would be appreciated. This is a very beginner code. Thank for your help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxEFV.png)

Comment: image of my code is in the enter image link.

Comment: By any chance is the last kids value in the file 2?

Comment: It is yes. line 31 is the value 2

Comment: Notice why the only kids value you add to the total is the last kids value?

Comment: Oh I see, there is no accumulation right?

Comment: Right. Accumulation of the total needs to take place inside your loop, just like it does with count.